# What does "call into work" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

Could tell me what *call into work* mean? For example:

> First things first, I have to **call into work**.

Does it mean briefly visit one's place of work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without context, it is impossible to be 100% sure what is meant, but 99.9% of the time it means

> to make a telephone call to your place of employment.

One reason that I cannot be completely positive is that it looks as though the speaker is not a native English speaker because

> First thing first

is not idiomatic. Why in the world would someone who has asked as many questions as you have neglect to provide any context whatsoever?

Comment: It was in "Breaking Bad". There wasn't much context